# Trimmer Line spool too loose inside head

Tags: weed-control

I have a single line auto feed weed whacker, that I've bought replacement line for.

The problem is that the line I bought is wound around a spool thats about 10cm in diameter, so when I wrap it around my line trimmer head which is only 5cm diameter, it "uncoils" inside the head because it tries to spring back to its manufactured coil. Basically that means the line thats extruded gets sucked back into the head.

How do I coil the line tighter so it behaves itself inside the trimmer head

Answer (score 1):

Other than winding new line in the correct direction , indicated by a arrow somewhere , there is not much to do . They are often a challenge . I cheated and put a steel blade on one of my trimmers , it does serious damage so is not for everyone.

Comment: I think that would qualify as an industrial solution for big weeds!